# Animação por JS sem erros no console, porém não funciona

Tags: javascript, funções, animação

Bom, estou criando uma animação do Tanque do clássico Metal Slug, porém, ao criar a função e executar ela para animar o tanque, nada acontece. O que há de errado, e como posso corrigir?

```
<body>
    <div id="tank-slug">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<style type="text/css">
    #tank-slug{
        width:196px;
        height:196px;
        margin:0 auto;
        background: url(images/Sprite-Tank-novo.png);
        background-position: 0px -10px;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:2px solid #000;
    }
    #tank-slug:before{
        content:url(images/Sprite-Background.png);
        width:196px;
        height:196px;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:-1;
    }
    #tank-slug:after{
        content:url(images/Sprite-Frontground.png);
        width:196px;
        height:196px;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;

    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function iniciaAnima(){
        setInterval(function(){
            var tankBack = document.getElementById("tank-slug");
            var count = 0;
            var valor = 100/55;
            var backPositionX = 0;
            tankBack.style.backgroundPosition = backPositionX + "px -10px";
            if(count < 100){ return count = count + valor }
            backPositionX = backPositionX + 190;
            console.log(tankBack.style.backgroundPosition)
            console.log(count);
        },500);
    }iniciaAnima();
</script>
```

Comment: E esse `var backPositionX = 0;` não devia estar fora do `setInterval`?, assim está a ser apagado a cada vez que o `setInterval` corre...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta assim :

```
function iniciaAnima(){
    var tankBack = document.getElementById("tank-slug");
    var count = 0;
    var valor = 100/55;
    var backPositionX = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        tankBack.style.backgroundPosition = backPositionX + "px -10px";
        if(count < 100){ return count = count + valor }
        backPositionX = backPositionX + 190;
        console.log(tankBack.style.backgroundPosition)
        console.log(count);
    },500);
}
```